# laravel what is different between post and other in web.php

Tags: laravel, post, get

I'm trying to understand clearly in laravel the difference between 4 lines (Post, Get and Match and Any) lines in the web.php,

like this.

using post:

```
Route::post('/admin/add_coupon','CouponsController@addCoupone');
```

using match:

```
Route::match(['get','post'], '/admin/add_coupon','CouponsController@addCoupone');
```

using any:

```
Route::any('/admin/add_coupon','CouponsController@addCoupone');
```

My questions are what is different all three above when running the same! which one is the latest version that best code can use for e-commerce website! and why we have three different ways to write code! are they using for speed, or save code or quality of code! I'm having hard time to decide which way to write code for heavy website! any advice!
many thanks.

Comment: The difference is the HTTP method it handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about HTTP verbs or REST API Verbs (https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/).

- **Post**: Only `POST` method
- **Match**: `GET` y `POST` methods (in your example)
- **Any**: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc

I recommend that you use routes and controllers type "resource" (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers)